# Is it possible to access tags located in a partial view from my css file (external file)?

Tags: css-selectors, asp.net-mvc-partialview

Let's say, I've got this.

```
<div id = "myDiv">
   <% Html.RenderPartial("MyUserControl"); %>
</div>
```

and inside my partial view, I've got this.

```
<% = htm.TextBox("myTextBox")%>
```

How can I style this tag from my ***Site.css*** file under Content folder? For instance, I want the back ground color to be green.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess if I did not get an answer until now, it's probably because I didn't ask clearly my question. Anyway, after hours of struggling, I found out how to deal with this.

The following tag <% Html.RenderPartial(string); %> is just a placeholder. So when the page executes, everything is merged (Master page, the view itself, the partial page, etc.). That implies I can target any element anywhere from my external css file by just keeping in mind the real location of that element in the final document.

for instance,

```
<div id="myDiv"> <% Html.RenderPartial("myPartialView");%></div>
```

inside mypartial view, i've got this,

```
<input type="submit" value = "Go"/>
```

I can access my input element this way:

```
#myDiv input { background:blue;}
```

Because, in reality, when the application executes, the whole document will present like this

```
<div id="myDiv">
     <input type="submit" value = "Go"/>
</div>
```

Hope that I didn't write falsehood.Otherwise correct me.

Thanks for helping.